# AUTHORIZATION WITH ID #30652927657716240 NOT FOUND - return true

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have an interactive grid with a modal form for add new rows, the form has nothing particular, just text input.

An error appear if I click on create button with a **Validation Process** setted to the form region. I tried this also on other pages and I have the same behavior. The only case this not happen is if I set like **Editable Region** an item like a grid inside the form, but I don't want this because I need to do a control on the creation.

The error is :
**AUTHORIZATION WITH ID #30652927657716240 NOT FOUND - return true**

I'm using **Oracle Apex 21.1**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem and when I check the application, I noticed some attribute causing this error.
In my case, the error is resolved, so I advise you to check also the application's shared components -> security attributes -> authorization scheme attribute. (In my case it was a invalid item displayed as just like in the error message you are also getting like: '30652927657716240').
I believe this is caused by copying the application, scheme or workspace from somewhere else. [image]

I hope changing this attribute a valid item from select list fixes your issue too.